# C++11 book notation

Tags: c++, templates

Could someone explain to me this notation from Stroustrup's book?

```
template<typename Cont, typename Pred>
std::vector<Value_type<Cont>*>
find_all(Cont& c, Pred p)
{
    std::vector<Value_type<Cont>*> res;
    for(auto& x :c)
        if(p(x)) res.push_back(&x);
    return res;
}
```

How should I understand `value_type` here? This is not a keyword from C++ and not `Cont::value_type`, then what?

The example is form C11 Bjarne Starstroup book.
Chapter 32.2 Algorithms snippet 4th.

Comment: `Value_type` must be defined somewhere before this code in the book

Comment: It is probably something like `template <typename T> using Value_type<T> = typename T::value_type;`

Comment: @OP, do you feel NathanOliver's comment provided the clarification you needed?

Comment: Please also mention the title of the book, version, and page number. Stroustrup has three published books about C++, one of which is on its fourth edition.

Comment: This code segment seems to be missing context. We can only determine what the context is if either you give us all the relevant code, or tell us where we might find all the relevant code. I *think* I've tracked this code snippet down to *The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition* on page 672. But I can't confirm, since I don't own any of Stroustrup's books, and Amazon doesn't allow searching the texts of his other two books. It very well may be present elsewhere, and I would have to find this book to confirm that this snippet *is* on that page--Amazon doesn't show the context search results.

Comment: @jaggedSpire I have this book and the snippet on page 672 doesn't match the one in question. And most probably it's not this book, as there is no mention of `Value_type` in the index (of course, there is `value_type`).

Comment: @BartoszKP Darn, thanks for checking. That was my only guess, too.

Comment: I'm voting to close as *Unclear what you're asking* because at the very least we need to know the book, edition, and chapter to find the snippet ourselves and verify we're supplying a good answer. If you add this information, or something more specific, please ping me @jaggedSpire so I can vote to reopen.

Comment: @jaggedSpire The requested information added. There was also a mistake. This example is from C11 not C14 book.

Comment: See Page 84 of The C++ Programming Language Fourth Edition by Bjarne Stroustrup. Chapter 3: Abstraction Mechanisms. Just search for `value_type on google` or stack overflow to learn more. The book also has references to later chapters from chapter 3.

Comment: And in the book is clearly Value_type not value_type!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See 28.2.4 of the book.

```
template<typename T>
using Value_type = typename std::iterator_trait<T>::value_type;
```

Comment: And now we are talking. Thanks. First non-evasive answer :)

Comment: Shame 4 the rest.

Comment: By the way std::iterator_traits :P